# Why string is not printed?C++

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Array{
public:
    T U[10];

    friend void DataOut(Array<string>);
    friend void GetData(Array<string>);
};

void DataOut(Array<string> Array1){
    cout << Array1.U[0];
}

void GetData(Array<string> Array1){
    cin >> Array1.U[0];
    cin.clear();
}

int main(){
    Array<string> Arr1;
    GetData(Arr1);
    DataOut(Arr1);
}
```

I made a class template and created two functions: `GetData` for entering string and `DataOut` for printing that string, but after entering string it doesn't print it. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Pass by value instead of by reference. As in, what you are doing vs. what you should do.

Comment: It might be because you are passing a copy of the variable `Arr1`into `Getdata` rather than a reference to it.

Comment: But how to use the reference?

Comment: The answer to that sub question [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242).

Answer (score 1):

I placed comments where I made changes. The main fix is to pass your object by reference, especially to `Getdata()`. You passed a copy, put data into the copy, and when the function ended, the copy goes away and your original object was never touched.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Array {
 public:
  T U[10];

  friend void DataOut(
      const Array<string>&);  // CHANGED: Need to take object by reference
  friend void GetData(Array<string>&);  // SAME
};

void DataOut(const Array<string>& Array1) {  // SAME
  cout << Array1.U[0];
}

void Getdata(Array<string>& Array1) {  // SAME
  cin >> Array1.U[0];
  // cin.clear();  // CHANGED: Why?
}

int main() {
  Array<string> Arr1;
  Getdata(Arr1);
  DataOut(Arr1);
}
```

Comment: Why? To clear out the data left in the stream of course! Why else would you call a function named `clear`? To clear error flags?

Comment: @user4581301: Clearing error flags is what it does, if you want to flush the remaining data that would be `ignore`

Comment: It seems unnecessary here is what I was intending. I know what it does.