# Some friend functions of a template class exhibit undefined reference

Tags: c++, templates, friend, friend-function

Was originally working on a question someone else asked earlier: [Why string is not printed?C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67540674/why-string-is-not-printedc). Seeing that OP was not quite utilizing the template for `DataOut` and `GetData`, so I was trying to make them template as well.

Here's the code I end up having:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class T>
class Array{
public:
    T U[10];

    friend void DataOut(const Array&);
    friend void GetData(Array&);
};

template<class T>
void DataOut(const Array<T>& arr){
    std::cout << arr.U[0];
}

template<class T>
void Getdata(Array<T>& arr){
    std::cin >> arr.U[0];
    std::cin.clear();
}

int main(){
    Array<std::string> Arr1;
    Getdata(Arr1);
    DataOut(Arr1);
}
```

However, I got undefined reference for `DataOut`: `main.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to 'DataOut(Array<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&)'`

I found two ways to get around this:

1. Define the `DataOut` inside the `Array` class.
2. Call `DataOut<std::String>` in main, instead of just `DataOut`.

---

The question is, how come no errors happens to `GetData`? I also tried to call and define them in different orders, but still the same result.

Is there something I'm missing? Or it's my compiler's (`clang 7.0.0`) fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared two (families of) non-template friend functions

```
template<class T>
class Array{
public:
    T U[10];

    friend void DataOut(const Array&);
    friend void GetData(Array&);
};
```

If you want that such a non-template function would be a friend function for a specialization of the class template you have to define it explicitly for that specialization.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class A
{
private:
    T x = T();
    
    friend void f( const A & );
};

void f( const A<int> &a )
{
    std::cout << "a.x = " << a.x << '\n';
}

void f( const A<std::string> &a )
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "a.x is empty = " << a.x.empty() << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    f( A<int>() );
    f( A<std::string>() );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
a.x = 0
a.x is empty = true
```

If for example you will add the following statement in main

```
f( A<long>() );
```

then the compiler will issue an error because there is no such a non-template function. Such function for this specialization of the class template is not defined.

You could define the friend non-template function within the class. In this case the so-called templated entity will be instantiated for each specialization of the class template by the compiler.

That is this function template declaration

```
template<class T>
void DataOut(const Array<T>& arr){
    std::cout << arr.U[0];
}
```

has nothing common with the non-template friend function `DataOut`.

As for this question

> The question is, how come no errors happens to GetData? I also tried
> to call and define them in different orders, but still the same
> result.

Then you have a typo in naming the function in the class and outside the class. That is you have two different functions `GetData` and `Getdata`.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Do you see that GetData and getData are two different names? That is you made a typo and declared two functions with different names.

Answer (score 0):

Vlad answer most of my question. Meanwhile I figured how to define the friend function as template functions from some gcc warnings:

```
template<class T>
class Array;         // Forward declaration of the Array<T> class

template<class T>
void DataOut(const Array<T>& arr){
    std::cout << arr.U[0];
}

template<class T>
class Array{
public:
    T U[10];

    friend void DataOut<>(const Array<T>&);    // `<>` used right after `DataOut`
}
```

Comment: Note that this makes the friend a template.  In the OP it was not.  This can cause some behaviour changes.